# Send XML file to URL Location

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmlhttprequest

**Sample XML File:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <queue>
  <txt>d15869d856df1ca3a749d071921f29f8</txt>
  <id>d15869d856df1ca3a749d071921f29f8</id>
 </queue>
```

for example in `iranfairco.com/getXml` getXml get a file xml from external request for example from other site.

now how can send this xml to this url??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question i udnerstand its a simple Post or Get to a URL, hence I suppose you could use System.Net's HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes for posting data, including XML data.

Comment: GET wouldn't be suitable for this due to length limitations and it fundamentally breaks what GET was designed for, only POST would be recommended.